# How to add JavaScriptInterface in Flutter WebView or InAppWebView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

In Android I can add javascript interface:

```
class JsInterface(private val onClose: () -> Unit) {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface    
    fun close() {
        onClose()    
    }
}
...
addJavascriptInterface(JsInterface { this@WebViewActivity.finish() }, "client")
```

How can I do **the same** in Flutter WebView or InAppWebView or other packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to read [this](https://blog.codemagic.io/inappwebview-the-real-power-of-webviews-in-flutter/) article, where they take a closer look at `flutter_inappwebview`. But try this code example for quick answer:

```
              InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: 'url',
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) =>
                    control.webController = controller
                      ..addJavaScriptHandler(
                        handlerName: 'serverSideJsFuncName',
                        callback: (data) {
                          // Catch and handle js function
                        },
                      ),
              )
```

On the other hand, if you want to update server side JavaScript you can do it via `InAppWebViewController` like this:

```
  Future<void> evalJs(dynamic param) async {
    await webController.evaluateJavascript(
        source: "window.someFuncName( '$param ');");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!
On the js side runs this code: " if(window.client) window.client.close() "
If just write " ..addJavaScriptHandler(handleName: 'close', callback: (data) {...}) " it doesn't work.
Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I am sorry but i don't think i can. Try to debug your actions from app against server. We also had some problems until we find correct way to access functions by their name from each mobile and backend. Try it with article i posted at JavascriptHandlers section.

Comment: Maybe you know how to add js interface via evaluate?

Comment: Evaluate is used to invoke some javascript functions on server from app. If you want to handle such function you have to define it like this 

            window.addEventListener("flutterInAppWebViewPlatformReady", function(event) {
                window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('handlerFoo')
                  .then(function(result) {
                    // print to the console the data coming
                   window.flutter_inappwebview
                      .callHandler('handlerFooWithArgs', 1, true, ['bar', 5], {foo: 'baz'}, result);
                });
            });

Comment: Each function must have "addEventListener("flutterInAppWebViewPlatformReady",..." and  window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('handlerFoo') to be registered by that WebView. Then you can invoke it by calling method as i wrote in example, but instead of "someFuncName" you will enter "handlerFoo". After this you should be able to handle JS from app.